C program structure and union bitfields
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t     ctr;
        uint8_t     write_ptr;
        uint8_t     read_ptr;
        unsigned    pause:1;            // To pause updating of arrays by the ISR
        unsigned        timed_out:1;
        unsigned        enable:1;
    };
    uint64_t    all:27;
} adc_array_flags_t;
extern      volatile        adc_array_flags_t   adc_array_flags;

I am programming C in atmega325a. I mostly use bitfields out of habit, even though memory space isn't usually a problem. I still think it's not bad to try to pack flags to save space. Actually, another reason is that it seems organized of all flags/counters related to the same topic (example: adc-related flags) are packed into single structure so that when I want to use an adc-related flag, I can just type "adc_flags."
I am having some doubts about the code above. Usually back then, the total size of union is 8 or 16, and in avr gcc, unsigned (or unsigned int) is 16 bits so I usually use unsigned int as type for the "all" variable. Also normally, my bit field is composed of multiple 1-bit flags. But in the code above, I wanted to see if I can pack multiple 1-bit flags plus some unsigned integer counters, all related to adc so I was thinking I might pack them all into a single structure.
Then I want to make a variable "all" that occupies the same space as the structure bitfield so I can easily reset everything with one line of code like: "adc_array_flags.all = 0".
However, is the line "uint64_t all:27;" valid? Recommended or not?
Most of the codes I see almost always uses an exact integer (not allocated to user-defined number of bits) for the "all" variable, such as uint32_t. But that defeats the purpose (I believe) of trying to use the smallest number of bits possible for this set of structure flags.
I am expecting that the compiler will still use 27 bits due to defined 27 bits of the "all" variable.

There's no guarantee that the 27-bit field will overlap with the struct as you want. The three 1-bit fields aren't necessarily contiguous with the three 8-bit members.

So using "uint64_t all' instead of "uint64_t all:27;" will make sure that "all" bitfield will overlap with the structure? (Altho the total size of the union will become 64-bits now)

Right. You should probably just use uint32_t. Theoretically there could be padding that makes this incorrect, but it's unlikely.

I guess you should put the bit fields in unsigned char rather than unsigned.

Honestly, what you doing seems like a recipe for failure, your code will be no portable at all and the slightest change in your data structure would cause a disaster. Change your compiler, or even some options to your compiler, and you might break your code, change the compiling target and you will break your code. You have endianess, padding and alignment to cause potential problems that will break your code here and give you infinite room for undefined behavior. Anyway, I think it's not clear to me what is your specific question here.

I agree with that. What do you think you need the all member for? If you want to access everything, just refer to the struct as a whole.

If I were going to try it (I probably wouldn't, but…), I'd make all the elements of the structure have type uint8_t, and I'd use uint32_t instead of uint64_t for the all member.  I think you'd have at least a chance of it working then.   As it stands, there's quite likely to be 8 padding bits after read_ptr and the 3 bit-fields would occupy a 32-bit storage area.  You would then need uint64_t for all, but you'd have some indeterminate bits (corresponding to the padding bits) in the middle of your 64-bit numbers.  Of course, it also depends on the layout of the ADC control bits.

Why would you want to use such a brittle design on an 8 bit MCU? Zero all structure fields explicitly, and the resulting machine code will be the same, most probably, or at least comparable in size and speed. The additional gain is the clear expression of your intend for the next source reader, which includes your future self.

@user139731 "I still think it's not bad to try to pack flags to save space." --> Each coding approach has advantages and disadvantages.  Perhaps the comments and answers will illuminate the disadvantages you did not think of before.

sizeof(adc_array_flags_t)==8
Test the code with a printf("%ld\n",sizeof(adc_array_flags_t)); It should say '8', even though you only defined 27 bits worth of storage. (comment out the uint64_t all:27; line and your answer reduces to "4" again)
The uint64_t tells the compiler that the requested bitfield should be packed in 64 bits of memory storage. Even though you only want to know about the “first” 27 bits, you are asking for it to occupy 64 bits (8 bytes) of storage.
I put “first” in quotes, because this raises a nasty aspect of bitfields: They’re not very portable.
Using C bitfields, accessing hardware registers, code portability: pick two
The C standard gives no guarantee about the order in which bits are assigned in a bitfield, and that makes them not very useful when you’re trying to access hardware, or create cross-platform or cross-compiler code.
GCC packs bitfields starting from the MSB and working down, adding additional bytes as needed, so pause would be 0x80, timeout 0x40 and, enable, but that is only what GCC does, and there’s no guarantee that another compiler will play along.  It’s even allowed for a compiler to insert padding bits between bitfields in order to ensure that none lie cross a machine-word boundary!
If this is a hardware register that you’re mapping, then you really do need to know the exact position of bits in memory, so you should not rely on things like the exact flavour of compiler being used.
Unfortunately, if you need to be sure of the location of individual bits, you will have to resort to storing bytes and using AND-masking, as follows:
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t     ctr;
        uint8_t     write_ptr;
        uint8_t     read_ptr;
        uint8_t     flags;
    };
    uint64_t    all;
} adc_array_flags_t;


enum {  // bits within 'flags' byte
  adcarrayflag_pause_mask = 0x80,          // To pause updating of arrays by the ISR
  adcarrayflag_timed_out_mask = 0x40,
  adcarrayflag_enable_mask = 0x20,
};

Just remember, logic-& and == are dangerous together.
As ever, I include the obligatory public-service announcement that & binds with lower precedence than ==, so expressions like

if ( p->flags&adcarrayflag_timed_out_mask == 0) wrong - always false!

must be written as:

if ( (p->flags&adcarrayflag_timed_out_mask) == 0)


Re “The uint64_t tells the compiler that the requested bitfield should be packed in 64 bits of memory storage”: The C standard does not say this. C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 says “An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field.” That is independent of the declared type of the bit-field. I do not see any explicit statement in the C standard about what the declared type of a bit-field actually means…

… My guess would be it is the semantic type of the bit-field when it is used in an expression. So, for int x : 3, x in x+3 would have type int. The compiler would be free to use one, two, or a million bytes for the bit-field. It could take the declared type as a request for the storage size except honoring that request would sometimes conflict with the next sentence in 6.7.2.1 11: “If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.”…

…  So char x : 3; int y : 5 would require y to be packed into the one-byte storage unit started for char, not into a storage unit sized for an int.

Re “It’s even allowed for a compiler to rearrange bitfields in order to ensure none cross a machine-word boundary!”: The C standard allows the compiler to insert padding bits (skip to the next storage unit), but it does not allow reordering: The implementation must define whether it uses high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order, again per 6.7.2.1 11.

@EricPostpischil - Point taken about rearrangement, but on field size, note that the 6.7.2.1 (11) text you quote says “may”, not “shall”. In GCC, putting uint64_t field:27 into a struct allocates 8 bytes, while using uint32_t field:27 allocates 4. Try it yourself.  As far as I can deduce, it uses the type of the first bitfield in any given run of bitfield fields to set the minimum size, but I didn’t try to reverse engineer it. My point stands: bitfield memory representation should not be relied on between compilers or architectures.

@KrisW, printf("%ld\n",sizeof(adc_array_flags_t)); better as printf("%zu\n",sizeof(adc_array_flags_t));.  "%ld\n" here risks UB.
